# How can I convert from uppercase to lowercase all directories and sub-directories in Ubuntu 16.04.2?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, directory, rename

Path:

```
/ DIRECTORY_ROOT
       /SUB_DIRECTORY
```

And convert that to:

```
/ directory_root
       /sub_directory
```

I tried: `rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *` but it only changes the root directory and not sub directories. I'm new to Ubuntu, thanks for the help!

Comment: Only rename directories or files and directories?

Comment: You don't want to do that. It'll break a whole bunch of stuff.

Comment: @Byte Commander only directories

Comment: You don't want to be renaming systems files or directories to lower-case.  Linux is case sensitive, and it will not end well.  Things will stop working. For example your /etc/NetworkManager directory, or the /boot/grub/System.map......  file.

Comment: heynnema & SunnyDaze - Thanks, this is just a directory that I created nothing with the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /path -depth -exec rename 'y/[A-Z]/[a-z]/' {} ";"
```

Here is a simple directory structure:

```
$ mkdir -p A/B/C/D
$ tree
.
└── A
    └── B
        └── C
```

and after running `rename` using `find`:

```
$ find /path -depth -exec rename 'y/[A-Z]/[a-z]/' {} ";"
$ tree
.
└── a
    └── b
        └── c
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need, but when I run `$ find /path -type d -execdir rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' {} +` I get the following: `Replacement list is longer than search list at (eval 4) line 1.` the program exits and it just changes the first letter of the root directory to lower case everything else, including sub-directories stays the same. How would you proceed? thanks again!

Comment: @Jacman your modification has been applied in my answer ;) thanks :-)